# Java FileNotFoundException even if the file exists

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I'm building an app where I need to store a `HashMap<Integer, User>` containing users' information into a file. Whenever the program starts, if `users` file doesn't exist it will create a new empty file, and whenever a new user registers I call the function `saveUsers()` which saves the `HashMap` into the file. When a user wants to login, I call the function `loadUsers()` which reads the file and store the object in the `HashMap` named `users`. The problem is that the program always throw a `FileNotFoundException` whenever I call `loadUsers()` even if the file exists, and using the absolute path.

Here are my functions :

```
public void saveUsers() throws IOException {
    File file = new File(usersFile);
    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
    s.writeObject(users);
    s.close();
}

public void loadUsers() throws IOException {
    File file = new File(usersFile);
    //System.out.println(file.exists()); always returns false
    //System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath().exists()); always returns false
    FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(file);
    ObjectInputStream s = new ObjectInputStream(f);
    try {
        users = (HashMap<Integer, User>) s.readObject();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    s.close();
}
```

Inside the login function :

```
try {
        loadUsers();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        // Here I always get this :
        // java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Me\Desktop\users.dat
        // (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    }
```

The `Users` class is **Serializable** and **`usersFile = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\users.dat"`**

I tried using **`file:///`** at the beginning, **forward slashes** and **backslashes** but nothing seems to work.

When I run `dir C:\Users\Me\Desktop\users.dat` in command prompt I get this :

```
Directory of C:\Users\Me\Desktop\users.dat

06/04/2020  01:03               616 users.dat
           1 File(s)            616 bytes
           0 Dir(s)  54,714,023,936 bytes free
```

Exception and stack trace :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Me\Desktop\users.dat    
(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at com.APP.loadUsers(APP.java:710)
    at com.APP.login(APP.java:722)
    at com.APP.lambda$6(APP.java:221)
```

**Edit :**

I tried this :

```
public void loadUsers() throws IOException {
    try (ObjectInputStream s = new 
    ObjectInputStream(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(usersFile)))) {
       try {
            users = (HashMap<Integer, User>) s.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And got this error :

```
> at index 33: C:\Users\Me\Desktop\users.dat <

    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:182)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)    
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)     
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)  
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:84)
```

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Try separating path using `File.separator` instead of slashes.

Comment: did you check `file.exists()` method

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: I checked both `file.exists()` and `file.getAbsolutePath().exists()`

Comment: *"even if the file exists"* Prove it: In command prompt, run `dir C:\Users\Me\Desktop\users.dat`, then edit the question and show us the output.

Comment: Also show us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. a small program with that `loadUsers()` that you run from the command prompt. --- Related question: How are you running the code right now?

Comment: the file exists because when i save it actually saves without any problem, and i'm running the program by vscode debug

Comment: `File.separator` didn't work either

Comment: Please provide the actual exception and stack trace, in your question.

Comment: *"at index 33"* That's really weird, since the string is only 29 characters long. Seems [answer by rzwitserloot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61051057/5221149) is on point, you have extra invisible Unicode characters in the string.

Comment: @Andreas I found out where the problem was. I was saving `usersFile` string in a different file along with other file paths separated by `$$`, I was reading it as a string then use `split("$$")`, and since the `usersFile` was the last one added to the list, the last character `\n` got stuck with it.

Comment: *"i'm running the program by vscode debug"* If you're running the code in a debugger, with an error like that, you should have looked at the value of `usersFile` to confirm the content. The `[13, 10]` in the value should then have been obvious and saved you a lot of time.

Answer (score 4):

The error strongly suggests there is a unicode character of some sort in that string. I suggest you delete the entire line and type it back in by hand to avoid this.

Alternatively, perhaps you 'cleaned' that name for the purposes of asking the question, in which case: Is there a fancy character in your name (something not from the ASCII range?) – then that's likely the problem.

You don't and shouldn't put `file://` in front of this; the right way for this style of code is: `File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Foo\\Bar");`

Comment: No actually the file is exactly `"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\users.dat"`

Comment: @mamokaze This answer is correct. The exception didn't say the file wasn't there, it said there is something wrong with the name. Retype it into your code. It isn't what you claim, which is legal. And surely you got the same error when you saved the file? If you did.

Comment: I had no errors when I saved the file. The only problem I got was when I wanted to read the file.

Comment: @mamokaze To verify beyond any doubt that no weird invisible character is in that file name, please add this to your code: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(usersFile.getBytes("UTF-8")));` --- It should print exactly this: `[67, 58, 92, 85, 115, 101, 114, 115, 92, 77, 101, 92, 68, 101, 115, 107, 116, 111, 112, 92, 117, 115, 101, 114, 115, 46, 100, 97, 116]`

Comment: @Andreas I got extra [13,10] .. that was the problem

Comment: @mamokaze Your question said `usersFile = "C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\users.dat"` as-if that's exactly what you had in your code. A `[13,10]` is `\r\n`, i.e. if those were in that quoted text, the source code wouldn't have compiled. Please don't ever again lie in a question like that, since it wastes the time of everybody, including yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The old Java File I/O API is notorious for generating misleading error messages. Use the newer NIO.2 API, which was added in Java 7.

You should also use try-with-resources, also added in Java 7. Unless you're stuck on ancient Java 6 or earlier, there is no good excuse for not using the newer APIs.

That would make your code look like this:

```
public void loadUsers() throws IOException {
    try (ObjectInputStream s = new ObjectInputStream(Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(usersFile)))) {
        try {
            users = (HashMap<Integer, User>) s.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Even if this still fails, it might provide a different error, like "access denied".